# Python Counter does not work. Or I forgot first grade matematics

Tags: python, counter

Well hello there,
I'm about to lose my mind, so I'll be glad if SOMEBODY helped.
The code is below. The output doesn't give me the right count.

```
import os, sys
from random import randint
from collections import Counter
import random

N = range(1,11)
print "N=" , N

#the stupid part below should take 10 random integers whose sum is equal to 10
def sum_to_ten(n):
    values = [1, 11] + [random.randint(2,n) for _ in range(n - 1)]
    values.sort()
    return [values[i+1] - values[i] for i in range(n)]
E = sum_to_ten(10)
print "E is: ", sum_to_ten(10)
N_E = dict(zip(N,E))
print N_E
#N_i should count the number of times an integer shows up, but does it? NO.
N_i = Counter(E)
print "N_i is:", N_i
```

Here's the output:

```
N is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
E is:  [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
N_E : {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 2, 9: 0, 10: 1}
N_i is: Counter({0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 1, 4: 1})


#See, N and E doesn't zip together to a dictionary correctly, and the counter doesn't count right.
```

Comment: I'm expecting N_i to be {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 3} did I get the idea wrong? Then how does it display the count?

Comment: Do you have any idea why they don't match? I'm stuck

Comment: You randomize in `sum_to_ten`. The printed `E` therefore is not the same as the counted `E`.

Comment: the value of E you are printing and the actual value of E are different.

Comment: I see, but still not sure how to fix it

Comment: Don't make 2 separate calls to `sum_to_ten` because the return value is different both times. Instead, use the return value you have already saved in E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
E = sum_to_ten(10)
print "E is: ", sum_to_ten(10)
```

Should be this:

```
E = sum_to_ten(10)
print "E is: ", E
```

Instead of generating and showing a different random array that has nothing to do with `E`.

Comment: Oh, I see, this fixes the problem. I didn't notice that thank you very much!